# How Can One Perform an Inventory of Users' Effective Permissions

Tags: sql-server

We have a number of SQL Server servers and databases each of which have Database Roles assigned to AD groups and, in some cases, roles assigned to specific users. AD groups might, of course, be nested. And, Database Roles might be nested into other roles. And, when one factors in DENYs, things get complicated.

I'd like to stay on top of it by periodically generating a report of each user's effective permissions. If I see anything suspicious, then I can dig into why they have the suspect permission.

What are some ways of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Yes, the  `DENY` really takes the fun out of tracking user's specific permissions, especially when they are nested in **Active Directory Groups** and **nested database roles**. You may want to consider rewording your question for a specific requirement, otherwise it might get closed as **Requires more focus**.  On the other hand you might want to reconsider your whole permission tree. It sounds frightfully complex.

Comment: @JohnK.N. It is a huge mess spread across 6 servers and 30 databases. Given the complexity, I was hoping an experienced DBA would just answer "use project XYZ". I'm surprised there isn't a product out there for staying on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually check this things with these two procedure:

server permission:
https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions/

database permission:
https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/